# Rails validation from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, controller

There is a contact page, which offers to enter name, telephone, email and message, after that it sends to an administrator's email. There is no reason to store message in DB.

Question. How to:

1. Use Rails validations in controller, not using model at all, OR
2. Use validations in model, but without any DB relations

**UPD:**

Model:

```
class ContactPageMessage
include ActiveModel::Validations
include ActiveModel::Conversion
extend ActiveModel::Naming

attr_accessor :name, :telephone, :email, :message
validates :name, :telephone, :email, :message, presence: true
validates :email, email_format: { :message => "Неверный формат E-mail адреса"}

def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
end

def persisted?
  false
end
end
```

controller:

```
def sendmessage
cpm = ContactPageMessage.new()
if cpm.valid?
    @settings = Setting.first
    if !@settings
        redirect_to contacts_path, :alert => "Fail"
    end
    if ContactPageMessage.received(params).deliver
        redirect_to contacts_path, :notice => "Success"
    else
        redirect_to contacts_path, :alert => "Fail"
    end
else
    redirect_to contacts_path, :alert => "Fail"
end
end
end
```

Comment: I think you have already have a class with the same name 'ContactPageMessage'. thats the issue.

Comment: Do you want to save name, telephone and email in the database and only message needs to be validated and not saved in the database?

Comment: @sumi, I don't want to be anything saved into DB. Just validated.

Comment: @RailsGuy, BINGO! Shame on me, I've used the same mailer class. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I think this is real downside of Rails validation that it's attached to ActiveRecord

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you should use model without inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` class.

```
class ContactPageMessage

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :whatever

  validates :whatever, :presence => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

Through this you will able to initialize new object and able to call validations on that object.

I think you have a different class name with same name, in your controller code, I can see this :

```
if ContactPageMessage.received(params).deliver
    redirect_to contacts_path, :notice => "Success"
else
```

if this is your mailer class change its name to `ContactPageMessageMailer`. you will no loger get that error.

Hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: I've got this: `private method'`new' called for ContactPageMessage:Class` (Using Rails 4, maybe error in this?)

Comment: Paste your application trace here.

Comment: and how you are calling the new method? write that here.

Comment: def sendmessage

   cpm = ContactPageMessage.new()

   if cpm.valid?

    @settings = Setting.first...

Comment: @Rom could you paste it in your question? It will be more readable.

Comment: @RailsGuy, thank you. I don't have reputation to vote for you, but I have choose your answer as best :)

Comment: I realized that after commenting, that's why I removed my comment.

Answer (score 6):

I would still advice you to use model, rails models doesn't have to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`. 
For example:

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :name, :telephone, :email, :message
  validates_presence_of :name, :telephone, :email, :message
  validates_format_of :email, with: EMAIL_REGEXP
end
```

and you can use it in your controller with:

```
contact = Contact.new
# ...
if contact.valid?
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

Answer (score -5):

In your model you can add the below which will just set getter and setter method for message and you can have validation on message without having a column in the db

```
attr_accessor :message
validates :message, presence: true
```

Comment: `class Contact`
`validates :message, :presence => true`
`end`
`# => NoMethodError: undefined method `validates' for Contact:Class`

Comment: If you already have a model and only few of the attributes you don't need to store it in the db then you can go with this option.  The above option you can include only on the Model which inherits from ActiveRecord::Base. If you want an independent Class which should acts as Model using Rails4 its very easy you just need to include ActiveModel::Model in you class and do the above. Ref [link](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html)