# Rails call custom validation before .new or .create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I make objects in controller's loop.

I need to check pet_name array before loop starts.
(because i got `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` when
`params[:pet_name].each do |pid|)` runs)

But my validation always called after User.new or User.create.
I want to change to validate as when i push submit button and check validation, and redirects back when pet_name array is nil.
Ho can i change my code?

Controller

```
  def create
    user_name = params[:user_name]
    
    params[:pet_name].each do |pid|
      @user = User.new
      @user.name = user_name
      @user.pet_name = pid
      render :new unless @user.save
    end
    redirect_to users_path
  end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pet

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :pet_name, presence: true
  validate :check_pet
  def check_pet
    if pet_name.nil?
      errors.add(:pet_name, 'at least one pet id')
    end
  end
end
```

Prams structure

```
  { name: 'blabla', pet_name: ['blabla', 'blablabla', 'bla'] }
```

Comment: because you have one default and one custom validation in your model. Please remove this 'validates :pet_name, presence: true' , if you only want custom validation.

Comment: @lhh thanks. but it still not work because of the loop's nill error

Comment: @lhh can i validate before loop creating?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve here? is there any specific value are you checking in Array before saving ?

Comment: @lhh i'm trying to validate if params[:pet_name] (array) is nil before create, but i just changed to check params before create. thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails validation from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965617/rails-validation-from-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but that isn't even close to how you approach the problem in Rails.

If you want a user to have many pets and accept input for the pets when creating users you need to create a working assocation to a Pet model and have the User [accept nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```erb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pets # has_many assocations should always be plural!
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :pets, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pets
end
```

```erb
# rails g model pet name user:reference
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    3.times { @user.pets.new } # seeds the form with blank inputs
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user, 
        success: 'User created',
        status: :created
    else
      render :new, 
        status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(:name, pets_attributes: [:name])
  end
end
```

```ruby
<%= form_with(model: @user) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_input :name %>
  </div>

  <fieldset>
     <legend>Pets</legend>
     <%= form.fields_for(:pets) do |pet_fields| %>
     <div class="nested-fieldset">
       <div class="field">
         <%= pet_fields.label :name %>
         <%= pet_fields.text_input :name %>
       </div>
     </div>
     <% end %>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is a pretty advanced topic and you should have your Rails CRUD basics well figured out before you attempt it. You should also consider if you instead want to use a separate controller to create the pets one by one as [a nested resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) after creating the user.